# Binding multiple events in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom jQuery plugin which binds a `change` event to a form element, in this case some `input` elements. The `change` event is used to indicate to some other components that a change has taken place.

This works as it should.

However, I've come across the need to bind an additional `change` event to the same `input` elements -- so that additional components can act on the event. I don't wish to replace the plugin's `change`, simply run an additional function afterwards.

Is there any way to bind multiple events in jQuery, or, what is the best method for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can bind multiple handlers for the same event. Bind the second change as you normally would:

```
​<input type="text" id="a" />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

​$("#a"​).change(function() { alert("1"); });
$("#a").change(function() { alert("2"); });​

$("#a").change(); // alerts 1, then 2
```

Comment: Ah cheers. I was under the impression doing so would replace the first function.

Comment: Does the same logic apply to using `bind()` with an object, instead of each individual function? As I didn't have the same success using `bind()`.

Comment: `change` is just a shorthand to `bind`, so it should work. what problems are you having with using bind? created a little example with passing a function reference to bind - http://jsfiddle.net/B9ggj/

Comment: Can you make sure that a certain order is followed?

Answer (score 7):

Events stack in jQuery. If you do:

```
<input type="button" value="Press me">
```

and:

```
$(":button").click(function() {
  alert("click");
}).click(function() {
  alert("click 2");
});
```

*both* will fire. So just bind another event to the relevant elements. It won't overwrite the first.